# Number of flagged posts for a user in the user profile shown in a meta site

Tags: support, profile-page, per-site-meta, flag-history, moderator-abilities

If I look at a user profile shown in a meta site where I am a moderator, should I see a link to the page listing the questions/answers posted by the user and that have been flagged (in the case there are any), as I see it in the main site?

The reason is I am asking is that I saw the overlay that it is shown when a question has been flagged, but the user profile for the OP doesn't show the link that reports the number of flagged questions/answers for that user.